# c++ declaring objects with curly braces

Tags: c++, declaration

When **declaring** objects in c++ -

What is the difference between

```
MyClass myObj (a,b,c);
```

(I understand this as invoking the constructor that takes three arguments)

vs.

```
MyClass myObbj{a,b,c};
```

Not sure what the curly brackets here mean?

As a reference I am using the following code

```
// Inertial Navigation EKF
NavEKF EKF{&ahrs, barometer, sonar};
AP_AHRS_NavEKF ahrs{ins, barometer, gps, sonar, EKF};
```

1.
Is the use of curly brace as in 
NavEKF EKF{&ahrs, barometer, sonar}; part of c++ standard.  gcc 4.6.1 complains that -  Function definition does not declare parameters.

2.
Given 
AP_AHRS_NavEKF ahrs;

AP_Baro barometer;

RangeFinder sonar;

2A. Why would the compiler complain about this

NavEKF EKF(&ahrs,  barometer,  sonar);

*but allow this*

NavEKF EKF(AP_AHRS_NavEKF &ahrs,  AP_Baro barometer,  RangeFinder sonar);

Comment: The lines of code you posted are both _declaration_ and _definition_, but I think _definition_ fits better in this context.

Comment: 1.
Is the use of curly brace as in 
NavEKF EKF{&ahrs, barometer, sonar}; part of c++ standard.  gcc 4.6.1 complains that -  Function definition does not declare parameters.

2.

Comment: Please see edited original post with follow up questions.

Answer (score 10):

The basic intent is that they usually mean the same thing. The big difference is that curly braces eliminate the "most vexing parse" where you tried to define an object, but end up actually declaring a function instead.

So, `NavEKF EKF{&ahrs, barometer, sonar};` is *usually* going to be equivalent to `NavEKF EKF(&ahrs, barometer, sonar);`. However, if you had something like: `NavEKF EKF();` vs. `NavEKF EKF{};` they're different--`NavEKF EKF();` declares a function named EKF that takes no parameters and returns a `NavEKF`, whereas `NavEKF EKF{};` does what you'd (probably) usually expect, and creates a default-initialized object named `EKF` of type `NavEKF`.

There are cases, however, where there's ambiguity about how to interpret things, and the ambiguity is resolved differently depending on whether you use parentheses or braces. In particular, if you use curly braces, and there's any way to interpret the contents as an initializer_list, that's how it'll be interpreted. If and only if that fails, so it can't be treated as an initializer_list, it'll look for an overload that takes the elements in the braces as parameters (and at this point, you get normal overload resolution, so it's based on the best fit, not just "can it possibly be interpreted to fit at all?")

Comment: Curly braces are also useful in case of primitive types, although, it is not related for this question.

Answer (score -1):

The curly braces is what is called 'uniform initialization'. The term is not part of C++ standard, but it is widely understood and is easily researchable. In particular, in the context provided, it means 'call constructor of MyObj with given arguments'.

Comment: Downvoter - learn to love to explain the reason for downvoting.

Comment: Not the voter, but the term "uniform initialization" is not used by the C++ standard. Also , "google it" isn't really an answer, that should be a comment at best.

Comment: This doesn't actually say what the difference is between using parentheses and braces.

Comment: gcc 4.6.1 gives me an error when using 
 NavEKF EKF{ &ahrs,  barometer,  sonar};
Function definition does not declare parameters

Comment: 4.6.1 is not C++11. You also need to make sure to specify -std=c++11 for compilation.

Answer (score -1):

Using parenthesis invokes a constructor, which then chooses how to initialize the data members as needed.

Using curly braces initializes the data members directly - unless there is a constructor defined that takes a `std::initializer_list` as input, in which case the braces form the list of values that gets passed to that constructor.

Comment: This is simply not true. In particular 'Using curly braces initializes the data members directly, bypassing any constructor' is nonsense.